# Command Prompt Unable to go to particular folder

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Actually I want to go to folder `Microsoft Office` in `Program Files` through my command prompt.

But When I go to the `Program Files`, `cmd` prompt shows me only two choices viz.

```
"Windows Alerter"
```

and

```
"Windows Common Files".
```

There are many other folders too, but it doesn't shows it.

Typing the whole name also didn't work.

It says, `system cannot find the path specified.`

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you're on a 64-bit system?  If that's the case, you would have `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Any chance you are on the wrong partition?  I have a 64-bit system.  I see both Program Files and Program Files (x86) neither has a Windows Alerter sub-folder.

Comment: Your computer is infected with this malware: http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Win32/Wecykler

Answer (score 1):

As nerdwaller suggested, 64bit systems have both `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` folders. Try both, and see if the folders show. Also, try using your Tab key when typing out folder names. This auto-completes file / folder names, and will help against spelling errors or situations where quotes are required. Lastly, try running cmd as Administrator, and see if this solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, find the folder in explorer, then copy the path into cmd to make sure it is right.

Then try `cd`ing to it (the `/d` is to change drives, incase your working directory is on another one).

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files"
```

Or `cd` to the drive where `Program Files` is and type `dir` to make sure it is there.

```
cd /d C:\
dir
```

Failing that, I can only assume something has gone horribly wrong with cmd :)